# Using synchronized block in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, synchronized, java.util.concurrent

I have the following code snippet:

```
public class Service<T> {
    private ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    public final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public Future<Boolean> foo(T o, String fileName) throws IOException {
        return exec.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws IOException {
                File f = new File(fileName);

//                synchronized (getCacheSyncObject(name.hashCode())) {
//                    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
//                        //some actions
//                    }
//                }

                try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
                    //some actions
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private Object getCacheSyncObject(final Integer id) {
        locks.putIfAbsent(id, id);
        return locks.get(id);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Object obj = new Object();

        Service<Object> service = new Service<>();
        Future<Boolean> result1 =  service.foo(obj, "filename"); // is there a deadlock?
        service.exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I want to complete one simple task. I need an exclusive file locking. To get this, I put lock on filename of file to synchronized block. But in this case, I don't get anything from `foo` method. My program does not end.

Comment: The program is going to create approximately as many locks as the number of distinct files that it reads in its lifetime.  (Or, if it runs for a looooooong time, the number of locks will asymptotically approach 2^32)  This may not be what you want.  If I was going to map files to locks, I would have a smaller pool of locks---probably some small multiple (2x or 3x) the number of files that I expect will ever be open at the same time.

Comment: You choose a lock based on the hash of the given pathname, but there can be many different pathnames that refer to the same file.

Comment: You said, "I need an exclusive file locking."  Most programmers who see the words "file locking" will think that you want to prevent two or more _processes_ from accessing the same file at the same time.  You might want to avoid saying "file locking" if you are only trying to synchronize the activity of two or more _threads._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a lock in scope of Service, you can use its field to store locks. But I'd suggest to don't use fileName.hashCode() because of possible collisions. Use the whole name instead:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

class Service<T> {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public Future<Boolean> foo(T o,
                               final String fileName) throws IOException {
        return exec.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws IOException {
                File f = new File(fileName);

                synchronized (getCacheSyncObject(fileName)) {
                    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
                        out.write("hi".getBytes());
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private Object getCacheSyncObject(final String name) {
        Object result = locks.get(name);

        if (result == null) {
            result = new Object();
            Object prevLock;
            if ((prevLock = locks.putIfAbsent(name, result)) != null) {
                result = prevLock;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object obj = new Object();

        Service<Object> service = new Service<>();
        Future<Boolean> result1 = service.foo(obj, "filename");
        service.exec.shutdown();

        System.out.println("result1 = " + result1.get());
    }
}
```

BTW, even you have a collision with hashCode(), you can get unexpected output in the file, but if you don't lock anything in that try

```
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
    out.write("hi".getBytes());
}
```

you shouldn't get a deadlock. I'd recommend to check your "//some actions"